# How to calculate the spread of values excluding extremes?

Tags: statistics

Suppose I have a set of values like this:

> 4.51
>   4.55
>   4.57
>   4.60
>   4.61
>   4.63
>   4.65
>   4.67
>   4.70
>   4.71
>   4.72
>   4.75
>   4.77
>   6.70

You can see that most of them are near to each other but the last one is far from them. What I want to achieve is to have an alogrithm which can calculate the spread without the extremes so it will return something like a range from `4,51` to `4.77` without `6.70`. There must be some statistical function or mathematical concept which I'm not aware of. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could run the data through a [median filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) to remove single outliers. However, this changes the statistics of the other data points too, and that in a way that I don't know anything about. You could try it and see if it's ok for your application.